# How to check if at least 2 arrays length is greater than 2 in Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have defined a separate interface class like this.

```
export interface FilterCriteria {
    continent: number[];
    country: number[];
    region: number[];
    city: number[];
    restaurant: number[];
}
```

In my component i have like this.

```
values: Filter = {
        continent: [],
        country: [],
        region: [],
        city: [],
        restaurant: [],
    };
```

And i want to check whether from any of these number arrays `this.values.continent, this.values.country, this.values.region, this.values.city, this.valuesrestaurant,`   at least 2 number arrays length is greater than 2. How to write a function for that?

Comment: What have you started with? For example, are you familiar with loops? The length property (this.values.continent.length)? Without knowing what you've started, it's difficult to know what more you need help with.

Comment: yea i know that .I want find whether at least any of the above 2 arrays length is greater than 2

Answer (score 1):

- First, declare a variable to count how many arrays that are greater than 2. `var count = 0;`
- Then loop through your values and check each arrays length if it's greater than 2 like this `if(this.values.continent.length > 2)`.
- If the condition is true just add increase the count by 1. `count++;`.
- When the loop ends you can see how many arrays are there that have lengths more than 2 by accesing `count`.

[Look at this tutorial about loop in angular](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angularjs-angular-foreach-function/#:%7E:text=forEach()%20Function%20in%20AngularJS,value%20pairs%20of%20an%20object.&text=Parameter%20Values%3A,the%20object%20to%20be%20iterated.)